# Creating HTML Fragments with PowerShell from CSV

Tags: html, powershell, csv, nested

I have a csv file that contains the following information

```
ParentID,DivID,DataElement,Content,Class
Dash_Reg,Summer_Active,Classes.Active,Active Classes:,class1
Dash_Reg,Summer_Active,Classes.Inactive,Inactive Classes:,class1
Summer_Active,Pass_classes,Classes.passed,Classes Passed:,class1
Summer_Active,Failed_classes,failed.classes,Failed Classes:,class1
Dash_FinAid,Award_Amount,Amount.Awarded,Amount Awarded:,class1
Award_Amount,Refund_Status,Refund.Status,Refund Status:,class1
```

The idea is to have PowerShell go through the csv and create the correct HTML code from it, to create proper nesting.  What this should create is the following HTML code:

```
<div id="Dash_Reg>
<div id="Summer_Active">
<p>Active Classes: <span id="Classes.Active"></span></p>
<p>Inactive Classes: <span id="Classes.Inactive"></span></p>
<div id="Pass_classes">
<p>Passed Classes: <span id="Classes.passed"></span></p>
</div>
<div id="Failed_Classes>
<p>Failed Classes: <span id="failed.classes"></span></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="Dash_FinAid>
<div id="Award_Amount>
<p>Amount Awarded: <span id="Amount.Awarded></span></p>
<div id="Refund_Status>
<p>Refund Status: <span id="Refund.Status"></span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

The script I wrote is as follows:

```
import-csv values.csv|group-object -property ParentID|export-csv test.csv
new-item paws.html -type file
$variableset = import-csv test.csv
foreach ($row in $variableset){
new-item (($row.Name) + ".html") -type file
add-content (($row.Name) + ".html") ("<div id='" + ($row.Name) + "'>")
}
$csv = import-csv values.csv
foreach ($row in $csv){
$dataelement = $row.DataElement
$DivID = $row.DivID
$content = $row.content
$parentid = $row.ParentID
$class = $row.Class
add-content (($parentid) + ".html") ("<div id='" + ($DivID) + "'>")
add-content (($parentid) + ".html") ("<div class='" + ($class) + "'>" + ($content)  +<span id='" + ($dataelement) + "'></span></div></div>")
}
add-content paws.html "<html><head><title>PAWS</title><link href='http://rsprodscd.gsu.edu/student-dashboard/assets/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet'></head><body>"
foreach ($row in $variableset){
$name = $row.Name
add-content (($row.Name) + ".html") "</div>"
get-content (($row.Name) + ".html")|add-content paws.html
rm (($row.Name) + ".html")
}
add-content paws.html "</div>"
add-content paws.html "</body>"
add-content paws.html "</html>"
```

That produces the following HTML code:

```
<html><head><title>PAWS</title><link href='http://rsprodscd.gsu.edu/student-dashboard/assets/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet'></head><body>
<div id='Dash_Reg'>
<div id='Summer_Active'>
<div class='class1'>Active Classes:<span id='Classes.Active'></span></div></div>
<div id='Summer_Active'>
<div class='class1'>Inactive Classes:<span id='Classes.Inactive'></span></div></div>
</div>
<div id='Summer_Active'>
<div id='Pass_classes'>
<div class='class1'>Classes Passed:<span id='Classes.passed'></span></div></div>
<div id='Failed_classes'>
<div class='class1'>Failed Classes:<span id='failed.classes'></span></div></div>
</div>
<div id='Dash_FinAid'>
<div id='Award_Amount'>
<div class='class1'>Amount Awarded:<span id='Amount.Awarded'></span></div></div>
</div>
<div id='Award_Amount'>
<div id='Refund_Status'>
<div class='class1'>Refund Status:<span id='Refund.Status'></span></div></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is to check if the ParentID exists as a DivID in the CSV and if it does nest that HTML code under the over arching parent ID.  Let me know if this makes sense or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way to do this was to build a function and go through the csv file recursively:

```
$csv= import-csv values.csv
new-item paws.html -type file
function build_structure
{
                foreach ($row in $csv){                 
if ($row.parentid -eq $args[0]){
add-content paws.html ("<div class='"+$row.divid+"'>")
build_structure($row.divid)
add-content paws.html ("<p class='" + ($row.class) + "'>" + ($row.content) + "<span id='" + ($row.dataelement) + "'></span></p>")
   add-content paws.html ("</div>")                            
}
}
}

build_structure("")
```

Comment: As posted, the script doesn't work. $row.parentid will never be equal to "" assuming that values.csv is the same as in the OP, which are: Dash_Reg, Summer_Active, Dash_FinAid, and Award_Amount.

Answer (score 0):

This produces the desired output from the data set given. You will need to change the convertfrom-csv to import-csv if your input is in a file. The desired output doesn't show the class (class1) as part of the output. You can easily add that if needed, by changing the line that outputs `<p>`. Also the desired output is missing a `</div>` at the end.

Note this code doesn't handle the case where you have two DivIDs that have the same name, but their parents have different names. Simplest way to take care of that is to make sure all DivIDs are unique.

```
$csvData = @"
ParentID,DivID,DataElement,Content,Class
Dash_Reg,Summer_Active,Classes.Active,Active Classes:,class1
Dash_Reg,Summer_Active,Classes.Inactive,Inactive Classes:,class1
Summer_Active,Pass_classes,Classes.passed,Classes Passed:,class1
Summer_Active,Failed_classes,failed.classes,Failed Classes:,class1
Dash_FinAid,Award_Amount,Amount.Awarded,Amount Awarded:,class1
Award_Amount,Refund_Status,Refund.Status,Refund Status:,class1
"@

$data = ConvertFrom-Csv $csvData

$divStack = new-object collections.stack

foreach ($item in $data) {
    #
    # Determine if Div or Parent Div is already open
    while ($divStack.count -ne 0 -and 
           $divStack.peek() -ne $item.DivID) {

        #
        # Div is not open. Determine if Parent Div is open
        if ($divStack.peek() -eq $item.ParentID) {
            #
            # Parent Div is open, now open Div
            $divStack.push( $item.DivID)
            "<div id=`"$($item.DivID)`">"
            break;
        } else {
            #
            # Div and Parent Div aren't open, try next one on stack
            $null = $divStack.pop()
            "</div>"
        }
    }

    #
    # Div and Parent Div weren't open. Open them
    if ($divStack.count -eq 0) {
        $divStack.push( $item.ParentID)
        $divStack.push( $item.DivID)
        "<div id=`"$($item.ParentID)`">"
        "<div id=`"$($item.DivID)`">"
    }

    "<p>$($item.Content) <span id=`"$($item.DataElement)`"></span></p>"
}
#
# Close all open Divs
while ($divStack.count) {
    $null = $divStack.pop()
    "</div>"
}
```

Comment: This didn't work.  Perhaps I worded my question weird but either way this had several errors when I tried to run as is.

Comment: I have an alias "new" for "new-object". I corrected the script.